# How to pass value from MySQL to go template

Tags: mysql, go, go-templates

This struct to pass value to template

```
type Entry struct {
    Name, Mes string
}
```

This function to handle with `HandleFunc("/", mysqlWithTempl)`

```
func mysqlWithTempl(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Open database
    con, err := sql.Open("mymysql", dbName+"/"+dbUserName+"/"+dbPassword)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Close database 
    defer con.Close()

    //query
    rows, err := con.Query("select name, message from entry")

    tRes := Entry{}

    //fetch result
    for rows.Next() {
        var name, message string
        rows.Scan(&name, &message)
        tRes.Name = name
        tRes.Mes = message
    }
    index.Execute(w, tRes)
}
```

and this template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="contents">
        <p> {{.Mes}} {{.Name}} </p>
       </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

my ask how can fetch more value from mysql and pass it to template

When try

```
 for rows.Next() {
            var name, message string
            rows.Scan(&name, &message)
            tRes.Name = name
            tRes.Mes = message
index.Execute(w, tRes)
        }
```

all result fetched but every thing repeated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be asking how to show multiple results?

If so then you want to accumulate all your rows into a slice like so:

```
results := []Entry
for rows.Next() {
    var name, message string
    rows.Scan(&name, &message)
    tRes.Name = name
    tRes.Mes = message
    results = append(results, tRes)
}
index.Execute(w, results)
```

Then your template will change to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="contents">
        {{range .}}
        <p> {{.Mes}} {{.Name}} </p>
        {{end}}
       </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe this will cause one `<p> {{.Mess}} {{.Name}} </p>` to be run per row that your mysql query returns.

I haven't actually tested this code though so it might have errors.

Comment: "I think you might be asking how to show multiple results?"
Yes, this is what I want thank you working well

Comment: You just saved my entire day by this `results = append(results, tRes)`